# Nested web component's `attachedCallback` not running on appended

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element

I'm playing with W3C web components.

I have a homepage, which includes component A:

```
<!-- homepage.html -->
<link rel='import' href='a.html'>
<component-a></component-a>
```

In component A I include another component B:

```
<!-- a.html -->
<link rel='import' href='b.html'>
<template>
  <component-b></component-b>
  <component-b></component-b>
</template>
<script>
  void function() {
    var currentDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument
    function getTemplate(selector) {
      return currentDocument.querySelector(selector).content.cloneNode(true)
    }

    var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
    proto.attachedCallback = function() {
      console.log('a')
      this.appendChild(getTemplate('template'))
    }
    document.registerElement('component-a', { prototype: proto })
  }()
</script>
```

B's code is very similar to A:

```
<!-- b.html -->
<template>
  <span>b</span>
</template>
<script>
  void function() {
    var currentDocument = document.currentScript.ownerDocument
    function getTemplate(selector) {
      return currentDocument.querySelector(selector).content.cloneNode(true)
    }

    var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
    proto.attachedCallback = function() {
      console.log('b')
      this.appendChild(getTemplate('template'))
    }
    document.registerElement('component-b', { prototype: proto })
  }()
</script>
```

What's weird is, when the page is loaded, I could only see `"a"` in console. I was expecting `"b"` for twice as well. And the component B isn't really parsed.

What even weird is that, if I run following code in console:

```
document.querySelector('component-a').innerHTML += ''
```

it suddenly gives me twice `"b"`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A friend gives me a solution, use [**`document.importNode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) instead of `cloneNode`:

```
function getTemplate(selector) {
  // return currentDocument.querySelector(selector).content.cloneNode(true)
  return document.importNode(currentDocument.querySelector(selector).content, true)
}
```

And it works perfectly.